# Is this a bug in Firebug?

Tags: javascript, firebug

I have the following javascript code:

```
function vocableToTextFieldClickEventHandler(e) {
if (e.keyCode == 13) { //Enter key
    if (pausedAfterAnswer) {
        pausedAfterAnswer = false;
        goToNextVocable();
        setAnswerNeutral();
        $("#vocableToTextFieldUI").val("");
        return;
    }
    if (textIsOnlyValidCharacters(vocableToTextFieldNode.value) == false){
        displayError("Not valid input!");
    }
    if (answerIsCorrect()) {
        displayAnswerCorrect();
        getActiveVocable().setPreviousAnswerStatus(1);
        pausedAfterAnswer = true;
    } else {
        repeatList.push("x");               //This line
        pausedAfterAnswer = true;
    }
}
}
```

When adding breakpoint to the line commented "This line", it triggers no matter what `e.keyCode` is. I've gone through this code snippet so many times to find the error, but can't seem to find it. I was just wondering if this might be a fault in Firebug or if it's just a silly programming error. I've had some strange behaviour from Firebug earlier today that didn't make sense either, so I really don't know if I can trust it.

Comment: so what does `answerIsCorrect` do? Does any of that stuff do asynchronous calls that answerIsCorrect should be (but isn't) waiting for?

Comment: try running it in chrome

Comment: `answerIsCorrect` only browses through an array and checks wether the text in a input field matches and item in an array. It shouldn't really matter  because it's not supposed to be executed as long as `e.keyCode` is not equal to 13. No async calls.

Comment: This is strange. If I write `alert("");` after `repeatList.push("x");` then it doesn't land on breakpoint.

Comment: What if you put `console.log(e.keyCode)` at the beginning?

Comment: Now suddenly it works as it should, but I haven't changed any code. That probably means something changes when I reload the page, but not every time. This is very confusing.

Comment: It started acting strange again now. I placed `alert("");` after `repeatList.push("x");` and made sure `e.keyCode` was 13 and `answerIsCorrect` is true, but the alert didn't show. Then I added `alert("")` after `if (e.keyCode == 13) { //Enter key` as well and did the exact same thing and then they both fired. This seems so strange, and it's probably a bad idea to post at a forum because it's difficult to explain.

Comment: Are you sure the breakpoint is set on `repeatList.push("x");` and not on the last statement `pausedAfterAnswer = true;`?

Comment: Yes. It was set correctly. What bugs me is that this strange behaviour doesn't happen every time I run the code so I suspect it's something going on in firebug or the browser rather than a fault in my code. I'll try clearing cache and resetting firebug if it happens again.

Comment: Okay, so I found a few faults(?) in firebug that may have been the cause of some of my confusement: 1: The Watch window in Firebug doesn't update unless I am stepping through the code or switching tabs. 2: When I'm stepping through the code, it skips some lines, but still executes them. This is a really bad bug and very annoying. The problem I had with code executing although it shouldn't (when `e.keyCode` was not 13, I still can't explain, but there is no point trying to solve it in a forum. Thank you for trying to help, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can not completely figure this one out, I can atleast conclude that some of the strange behaviour I experienced from Firebug can be fixed by going to the Firebug options and clicking "Reset all Firebug options" and then restarting the browser.